# I want to see who marked my questions as favorites

Tags: feature-request, bookmarks

Favorite data is not exactly confidential; I can go to a user's profile and see everything they have as a favorite. Why isn't there an easy way to see who marked my questions as favorite?

Answer (score 28):

My guess is that you could probably work up a query with some SQL-fu.

This site is usually pretty easy to work with:

> http://data.stackexchange.com

Example: [users who've marked my questions as favorites on Stack Overflow](http://odata.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/10142/who-favorited-me?UserId=5640)

For reference:

> https://blog.stackoverflow.com/category/cc-wiki-dump/

Answer (score 24):

I'd actually suggest going the other way: make my list of favorited questions private.  I don't see why anyone else needs to know which questions I like enough to come back to.

Comment: Cause after reading them, they may like them too?

Comment: I seriously and strongly disagree. Everything on the SE network should be public except in the cases of _some_ negative behavior (which should be removed in the first place).  I -1 this on account of it is bad juju.

Comment: the question is whether everything should be pubic

Comment: @PeterAjtai Maybe someone favorited [Is shaving your pubic hair bad for you?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/19198/is-shaving-your-pubic-hair-bad-for-you) ("for a friend"), but they don't want people to see that? And there's no reason for a user to think that clicking that star icon will be something other users can see?

Answer (score 8):

You could query the database:

https://blog.stackoverflow.com/category/cc-wiki-dump/

Answer (score 3):

There's no way to do this directly (Stack Overflow provides no mechanism to do so), but sometimes you can use Google to find out. As an example, suppose you wanted to find out who marked "[Jon Skeet Facts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/305223/jon-skeet-facts)" as favorite. Just search for

> "Jon Skeet Facts?" site:stackoverflow.com inurl:favorites

on [Google](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22Jon%20Skeet%20Facts?%22%20site:stackoverflow.com%20inurl:favorites).

Comment: repost from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/166109/how-do-favourite-questions-work-in-stack-overflow/615502#615502

Comment: It wouldn't exactly be a difficult SQL query to write and implement, either.

Comment: I tested this on a question that has 21 favorites; 4 came up and only 2 actually had it as a favorite. Not a very good success rate.

Comment: But it's success nonetheless!

Comment: @devinb: The number of result represented less than 20%, and 50% of that were false positives.  You have a very low standard for success.  I wish you were my boss.  "What did you accomplish today, Pesto?" "I added a line of code that only core dumps once in every 5 tries!" "SUCCESS!"

Comment: @thetxi Google query vs. SQL query...is there much of a difference any more...?

Comment: Google query - "Did you mean RIGHT OUTER JOIN?"

Comment: Honestly, who *didn't* mark that question as a favorite? ;)

Comment: I didn't.  In fact, I voted to close it when someone (no names mentioned here) removed the jon-skeet tag (that I have on ignored tags)

Comment: @TheTXI: I wonder what the difference is between write SQL and implement SQL

Answer (score 2):

This would allow to find people that have the same problems or interests. Nice feature for networking. Alternative: neighborhood graph based on tags in questions and answers.

Comment: Heh, interesting idea, that last one. Reminds me of last.fm which (as one of their many data mining features) produces a list of "neighbours" with similar musical taste

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you may be able to get this from the public data dump now, starting from the July 2009 dump: https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/07/creative-commons-data-dump-july-09/