# Don't show who voted to close a question

Tags: feature-request

OK, this will come across as brash, but I assure you it is very sound logic:

In [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39986/show-me-who-has-favorited-my-question-closed), and especially [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/824/i-want-to-see-who-marked-my-questions-as-favorites) it was made clear that SO is not a social network, so it didn't matter who followed you, so my questions are:

1. What value is there in seeing who voted to close a question (unless I'm an administrator), other than stirring up an argument? Why not remove that?
2. While we're at it, why not remove the star that shows how many people have favorited the question, if the favorite feature is only for the person using it? Let's remove that feature too.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Hide the names of the people who voted to close a question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54895/hide-the-names-of-the-people-who-voted-to-close-a-question)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Regarding voting to close and blame:

I'd imagine that it's too easy for people to close a question for a grudge or just to troll. Downvoting has that one-point penalty for the same reason, so people won't just run down a list of questions voting down people they don't like, or following people they don't like to vote down their historic questions/answers.

Regarding favorites vs upvotes:

I vote up questions I think are good questions. I favorite questions I think are useful (seeing as this puts them on a list I can refer back to in the future). I don't find every aspect of software development useful, so I don't favorite as many questions as I upvote. Occasionally, I'll be interested in the subject of a question, but I feel it's either a bad question or overrated, so I'll favorite it so I can come back to it in the future to see if it has aged well.

Answer (score 5):

It's for transparency. I like it.

The favorite count is used as a second indicator of the question quality. I like it too.