# Favorite Questions

Tags: feature-request, bookmarks

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [I want to see who marked my questions as favorites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/824/i-want-to-see-who-marked-my-questions-as-favorites)

I can see that one of my questions has been added as a favorite by another user.  I don't see how I can view who has marked it as a favorite.  It would be nice to know who favorited your question.  I am fairly new to the site so maybe there is a way to do this already.  If not then it would be nice to have the functionality added.

Comment: SO/SE is not a social network though. So I don't see why you would want that information. What would you do with it?

Comment: Do note that people use the "favorite questions" feature all different ways. In *theory* it might mean that they liked your question and wanted to save it for future reference. But in *practice*, it often just means that they temporarily "bookmarked" it, intending to come back to it. Maybe they weren't able to give a complete answer at the time but intend to do so later, or maybe they cast a close vote and want to make sure that the question actually gets closed, or whatever. It may not be *positive* feedback, or even feedback at all.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is not currently possible via the site as it is.

However, FWIW, since a user's favorites are public information, you could look up who favorited your stuff using the [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/).

Incidentally, I already made a query that does this: [Who favorited my questions?](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/63903/who-favorited-my-questions)

Comment: Hey, I didn't know that the Stack Exchange Data Explorer existed.  Thanks for letting me know.